# Python findall Regex function catches only some text

Tags: python, regex

I'm still new at Regex, and I've been trying to implement a Gmail validation algorithm in my Python program.

This is my Regex

```
mail_address = "hello.89@gmail.com"
result = re.findall(r'\w+[\w.]+(@gmail.com){1}', mail_address)
print (str(result))
```

The first char must be alphanumeric *(\w+)*, from there it catches every set of chars *([\w.]+)*, followed by only one instance of *@gmail.com*

This is what it prints:

```
['@gmail.com']
```

But it should print

```
['hello.89@gmail.com']
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's the Regex I chose:

```
\A(\w+[\w.]+@gmail\.com)\Z
```

Comment: Change to `(?:@gmail.com)` - this will change the string "@gmail.com" to non-capturing group.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Honestly, the group is not even needed (no quantifier!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just alter the parentheses so that it includes all of your desired output:

```
result = re.findall(r'(\w+[\w.]+@gmail.com)', mail_address)
```

I have slightly altered your expression insofar as the `gmail.com` part is now only a string. Additionally, you don't need to convert the results to string plus you don't need to repeat a group just once.
That being said, in the end, you'd end up having:

```
import re
mail_address = "hello.89@gmail.com"
result = re.findall(r'(\w+[\w.]+@gmail.com)', mail_address)
print (result)
# ['hello.89@gmail.com']
```

Comment: @иσαнcяişтiпσ: You were too quick.

Comment: Thanks, that was very quick and clear. I didn't know parentheses were obligatory with Python. Do I have to insert them in other languages too? I'm asking because I'm studying Regex in a generic book and parentheses aren't used at the beginning and at the end of the searched string.

Comment: @RiccardoLomazzi: Have slightly adjusted the regex once again. Parentheses form capturing groups, thus you will be able to access specific parts after habing matched the whole substring.

Comment: @Jan thank you, but without the quantifier the user could input  *hello.89@gmail.com@gmail.com*. I'd like him to write it correctly.

Comment: @Jan This is the regex I've found to work best: *\A(\w+[\w.]+@gmail\.com)\Z*

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in the parentheses as Jan mentioned. But your regex can be also simplified to this:

```
result = re.findall(r'(\w+[\w.]+@gmail.com)', mail_address)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Z5EGbZ/1

Quantifier after *@gmail.com* is meaningless.

Comment: If I avoid putting the quantifier, it also accepts *hello.89@gmail.com@gmail.com*

Comment: @riccardo-lomazzi Well, what do you mean by accepts? In the results will be only *hello.89@gmail.com* and the same behaviour is accomplished with or without quantifier. That's why quantifier is meaningless. Please check the demo.

Comment: By accept I mean it also takes the repetition as correct, but I want the user to insert it correctly.

Comment: This is the regex I've found to work best: *\A(\w+[\w.]+@gmail\.com)\Z*

Answer (score 1):

this should work, using your regex only

```
regex = r"\w+[\w.]+(@gmail.com){1}"

test_str = "hello.89@gmail.com"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

check [online compiler](http://ideone.com/V2NaYp)